# Proof of the inequality $t\left(\frac{0.5}{t^2+1} + 2\right) + 2\sin (4t) > 0, t > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How can the following inequality be proved?
$$t \left (\frac{0.5}{t^2+1} + 2 \right) + 2\sin (4t) > 0, t > 0$$
Any help would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Alternative solution: If $0 < t \le \pi/4$ or $t > 1$, it is obvious. If $\pi/4 < t \le 1$, let $f(t) = 2t + 2\sin (4t)$. We have $f'(t) = 2 + 8\cos (4t) \le 2 + 8\cos 4 < 0$ for all $t\in (\pi/4, 1]$. Also, $f(1) > 0$. Thus, we have $f(t) > 0$ for all $t\in (\pi/4, 1]$. We are done.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you! Make it better as an answer, I will definitely approve it with my like :)

Comment: You are welcome. It is fine as a comment since @angryavian has given a nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left-hand side is larger than $2 (t+\sin(4t))$ so it suffices to show that $t + \sin(4t) > 0$.

Note that $t + \sin(4t) \ge t-1 > 0$ for $t > 1$. For $0 < t \le 1$, you can verify $t + \sin(4t) > 0$ graphically, or use calculus to find the local minima.

Comment: ... And here I was, doing tedious algebra only to be able to prove this for $t\gt t_0$ where $t_0\approx 0.87609$ is the real root of the polynomial $4t^3-4t^2+5t-4$. Can't believe I missed this.